# Manage advertisements on my website

Tags: web-apps, advertising

I have a website, currently it has static banner ads (hard-coded)

I want a service where the ads on my website are dynamic and rotating between page loads and with the following functionality:

- I upload or specify banner url
- I set the total click-through rate *(or any other advertising model)* for a banner
- Geographic settings on a banner would be great but not absolutely necessary
- The service needs to record all the clicks, impressions, etc on each banner

Please recommend such a service or software.

Answer (score 1):

[Revive Adserver](https://www.revive-adserver.com/) is open source and has very extensive features. Installation and config is a bit complicated though. It uses php+MySQL.